# Defining height of triangle in coordinate system

Tags: java

I'm writing exercise program with user input of three points in coordinate system, so it get's you length of all sides of given triangle, so as perimeter and area. My goal is to ***define height*** of given triangle, so that i can tell if input points equals to straight line in coo-system, triangle doesnt exist, becouse height=0, also to define area of triangle.So how can i define height by given only A, B and C? Any suggestions for typing my code to look better is always welcome! :) 
So, my code looks like this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double aX;
        double aY;
        double bX;
        double bY;
        double cX;
        double cY;

        System.out.println("-Distance between 3 points in coordinate system-");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("point A(x):");
         aX = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("point A(y):");
         aY = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("point B(x):");
         bX = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("point B(y):");
         bY = sc.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("point C(x):");
         cX = sc.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("point C(y):");
         cY = sc.nextDouble();

         System.out.println();

         sc.close();

         double dX = bX - aX;
         double dY = bY - aY;
         double eX = cX - bX;
         double eY = cY - bY;
         double fX = cX - aX;
         double fY = cY - aY;

         double sD = Math.pow(dX, 2) + Math.pow(dY, 2);
         double d = Math.sqrt(sD); // length of d (from point A to point B)

         double sE = Math.pow(eX, 2) + Math.pow(eY, 2);
         double e = Math.sqrt(sE); // length of e (from point B to point C)

         double sF = Math.pow(fX, 2) + Math.pow(fY, 2);
         double f = Math.sqrt(sF); // length of f (from point C to point A)

         System.out.println("Distance from point A to point B is "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(d));

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("Distance from point B to point C is "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(e));

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("Distance from point C to point A is "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(f));

         System.out.println();

         double p = d+e+f; // (perameter)

         System.out.println("Perameter of triangle ABC is "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(p));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double p = d + e + f;
double area = Math.sqrt( p * (p-d) * (p-e) * (p-f) );
double heightD = (2 * area) / d; //height of edge d
```

according to question; d, e and f are edges of the triangle. you can calculate area by knowing an edge and height of that edge or by knowing 3 edges lenghts. If you know all edges lenghts, you can get height of an edge

Comment: please elaborate your answer with explanation. don't post just a code.

Comment: Yes, except for area goes semi-peimeter instead of perimeter.

Comment: Heron's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 2):

You want to find height of the triangle based on the given points, right? Every triangle has three heights, so you can calculate them using Heron's formula.

> For any triangle with sides a, b, c and semiperimeter `s = (a + b + c) / 2` the altitude from side `a` is given by: `ha = (2*sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)))/a`

Note that `a,b,c` here are the **lengths** of the sides of the triangle.

Then you can check if any of the heights are zero.

Comment: Yes, this looks good, thank you very much, and all other options from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The height of a 'real' triangle depends on which side is on the floor.  But you are looking for a non-triangle.  i.e. a non-triangle who's three points lie on a straight line.

To work this out you can simply work out the gradient of two of the 'sides'.  If they are the same then you know you have a 'non-triangle'

```
gradient1 = (y2 -y1)/(x2 - x1)
gradient2 = (y3 -y1)/(x3 - x1)
```

If `gradient1 == gradient2` then you have a 'non-triangle'.  As double type arithmetic can lead to slight difference you might want to be able to tolerate minor difference in gradient (e.g. if the difference is < 0.0001 then it's a non-triangle)

Update: Probably also need to cater for divide by zero error too!

Answer (score 0):

The height of the triangle is existent between three units.

The A) Base-A
The B) Base-B
The H) Height-C

A^2 + B^2 = C^2